# Not permitted to execute user plugin on Artifactory Pro

Tags: artifactory

I have written a user plugin for Artifactory.

However when I want to execute it I get this error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 405,
            "message": "You are not permitted to execute 'cleanUpPlugin'."
        }
    ]
}
```

This error occurs whether I use the *admin* account or don't use *Basic Auth* at all.

What do I have to do to be allowed to execute the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use the correct HTTP method (default is `POST`) to get the request working.